# Hooking NtQueryDirectoryFile can't hide files

Tags: winapi, hook

I want to hide files (in my program). I decided to use NtQueryDirectoryFile. But the files are not hidden, the code does not work. I don't use a driver, I use user mode. Can anybody help me please?

The code snippet:

```
typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI * NTQUERYDIRECTORYFILE) (IN HANDLE FileHandle,IN HANDLE Event OPTIONAL,IN PIO_APC_ROUTINE ApcRoutine OPTIONAL,IN PVOID ApcContext OPTIONAL,OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,OUT PVOID FileInformation,IN ULONG FileInformationLength,IN MYFILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass,IN BOOLEAN ReturnSingleEntry,IN PUNICODE_STRING FileName OPTIONAL,IN BOOLEAN RestartScan);

NTQUERYDIRECTORYFILE OriginalNtQueryDirectoryFile;

#define STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE 0xC000000F

NTSTATUS
  HookedNtQueryDirectoryFile(
        IN HANDLE FileHandle,
        IN HANDLE Event OPTIONAL,
        IN PIO_APC_ROUTINE ApcRoutine OPTIONAL,
        IN PVOID ApcContext OPTIONAL,
        OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
        OUT PVOID FileInformation,
        IN ULONG FileInformationLength,
        IN MYFILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass,
        IN BOOLEAN ReturnSingleEntry,
        IN PUNICODE_STRING FileName OPTIONAL,
        IN BOOLEAN RestartScan)
{
    NTSTATUS status = OriginalNtQueryDirectoryFile(FileHandle,Event,ApcRoutine,ApcContext,IoStatusBlock,FileInformation,FileInformationLength,FileInformationClass,ReturnSingleEntry,FileName,RestartScan);

    vector<wstring> listDataForHidding;
    listDataForHidding.push_back(L"afile.txt");
    listDataForHidding.push_back(L"bfile.txt");
    listDataForHidding.push_back(L"cfile.txt");
    listDataForHidding.push_back(L"dfile.txt");

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        PMYFILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION FileDirectoryInfo, LastFileDirectoryInfo;
        PMYFILE_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION  LastFileFullDirectoryInfo, FileFullDirectoryInfo;
        PMYFILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION  LastFileBothDirectoryInfo, FileBothDirectoryInfo;
        PMYFILE_NAMES_INFORMATION     LastFileNamesInfo, FileNamesInfo;

        ULONG Offset = 0;
        BOOL bNeedHide = FALSE;

        switch (FileInformationClass)
        {
            case FileDirectoryInformation :
                FileDirectoryInfo = NULL;

                do 
                {
                    //FileDirectoryInfo = (PVOID)((ULONG)FileInformation + Offset);
                    FileDirectoryInfo = (PMYFILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION)((ULONG)FileInformation + Offset);
                    LastFileDirectoryInfo = FileDirectoryInfo;

                    wstring wstrCurrFileName = FileDirectoryInfo->FileName;
                    bNeedHide = FALSE;
                    for(size_t index = 0; index < listDataForHidding.size(); index ++)
                    { 
                        if(wstrCurrFileName.find(listDataForHidding[index]) != wstring::npos)
                        {

                            bNeedHide = TRUE;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //if (FileDirectoryInfo->FileName[0] == 0x5F00)
                    if(bNeedHide == TRUE)
                    {
                        if (!FileDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset)
                        {
                            if (LastFileDirectoryInfo) LastFileDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset = 0;
                            else status = STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE;
                            return status;
                        } else 
                        if (LastFileDirectoryInfo) LastFileDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset += FileDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset;                        
                    }

                    Offset += FileDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset;

                } while (FileDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset);

            break;

            case FileFullDirectoryInformation :
                FileFullDirectoryInfo = NULL;
                do
                {
                    LastFileFullDirectoryInfo = FileFullDirectoryInfo;
                    //FileFullDirectoryInfo = (PVOID)((ULONG)FileInformation + Offset);
                    FileFullDirectoryInfo = (PMYFILE_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION)((ULONG)FileInformation + Offset);

                    wstring wstrCurrFileName = FileDirectoryInfo->FileName;
                    bNeedHide = FALSE;

                    for(size_t index = 0; index < listDataForHidding.size(); index ++)
                    { 
                        if(wstrCurrFileName.find(listDataForHidding[index]) != wstring::npos)
                        {    
                            bNeedHide = TRUE;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //if (FileFullDirectoryInfo->FileName[0] == 0x5F00)
                    if(bNeedHide == TRUE)
                    {
                        if (!FileFullDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset)
                        {
                            if (LastFileFullDirectoryInfo) LastFileFullDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset = 0;
                            else status = STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE;
                            return status;
                        } else 
                        if (LastFileFullDirectoryInfo) LastFileFullDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset += FileFullDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset;
                    }

                    Offset += FileFullDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset;

                } while (FileFullDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset);
            break;

            case FileBothDirectoryInformation :
                FileBothDirectoryInfo = NULL;
                do
                {
                    LastFileBothDirectoryInfo = FileBothDirectoryInfo;
                    //FileBothDirectoryInfo = (PVOID)((ULONG)FileInformation + Offset);
                    FileBothDirectoryInfo = (PMYFILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)((ULONG)FileInformation + Offset);

                    wstring wstrCurrFileName = FileDirectoryInfo->FileName;
                    bNeedHide = FALSE;

                    for(size_t index = 0; index < listDataForHidding.size(); index ++)
                    { 
                        if(FileBothDirectoryInfo->FileNameLength > 1 && wstrCurrFileName.find(listDataForHidding[index]) != wstring::npos)
                        {

                            bNeedHide = TRUE;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //if (FileBothDirectoryInfo->FileNameLength > 1 && FileBothDirectoryInfo->FileName[0] == 0x5F00)
                    if(bNeedHide == TRUE)
                    {
                        if (!FileBothDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset)
                        {
                            if (LastFileBothDirectoryInfo) LastFileBothDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset = 0;
                            else status = STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE;
                            return status;
                        } else 
                        if (LastFileBothDirectoryInfo) LastFileBothDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset += FileBothDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset;
                    }

                    Offset += FileBothDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset;

                } while (FileBothDirectoryInfo->NextEntryOffset);
            break;

            case FileNamesInformation :
                FileNamesInfo = NULL;
                do
                {
                    LastFileNamesInfo = FileNamesInfo;
                    //FileNamesInfo = (PVOID)((ULONG)FileInformation + Offset);
                    FileNamesInfo = (PMYFILE_NAMES_INFORMATION)((ULONG)FileInformation + Offset);

                    wstring wstrCurrFileName = FileDirectoryInfo->FileName;
                    bNeedHide = FALSE;

                    for(size_t index = 0; index < listDataForHidding.size(); index ++)
                    { 
                        if(wstrCurrFileName.find(listDataForHidding[index]) != wstring::npos)
                        {  
                            bNeedHide = TRUE;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //if (FileNamesInfo->FileName[0] == 0x5F00)
                    if(bNeedHide == TRUE)
                    {
                        if (!FileNamesInfo->NextEntryOffset)
                        {
                            if(LastFileNamesInfo) LastFileNamesInfo->NextEntryOffset = 0;
                            else status = STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE;
                            return status;
                        } else 
                        if (LastFileNamesInfo) LastFileNamesInfo->NextEntryOffset += FileNamesInfo->NextEntryOffset;
                    }

                    Offset += FileNamesInfo->NextEntryOffset;
                } while (FileNamesInfo->NextEntryOffset);

            break;
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain conceptually what you are doing here. What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening. This looks like malware.

Comment: Indeed why would anyone want to hide files from the user except for malicious reasons?

Comment: @Xearinox: I may be a bit biased because I'm used to Linux and open-source, but **I** am in control of my machine and the programs that run on it, and if a program tries to hide something from me then it **is** malware whatever the program's developer thinks or says. Security is about preventing bad stuff to happen (and telling the user he can't do it) not about hiding stuff from the user.

Comment: The correct way to do what you're trying to do is a filter driver. It could also be considered a root kit and so, malware.

Comment: Please try to be more specific in your question, this makes it easier for others to help you.